# Unique Counts in Teradata per column

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a dataset that consists of the following

```
ID     SubID
1        1
1        2
2        1
3        1
```

I want a third column that basically flags the first ID and any subsequent IDs which are the same are ignored
In essence someone (end user) wants to keep the details but also sum up the unique IDs in excel

```
ID     SubID  ident
1        1      1
1        2      0 
2        1      1
3        1      1
```

I suspect i can use a `rank` function here but would appreciate any hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No RANK, but a ROW_NUMBER:

```
select ID, SubID, 
   case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SubID) = 1
        then 1 
        else 0
   end
from tab
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by id order by subid) = 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as ident
from t;
```

Given your sample data, this simpler version would work:

```
select t.*, (case when subid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ident
from t;
```

If this is true for all your data, then the extra column may not even be necessary.  The user can use `sumif()` or `countif()` to do the conditional logic in Excel.